# What happens when you try to upvote a question (or an answer) but you don't have enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, up-votes

When you try to upvote a question or an answer and you don't have enough reputation (15 points, it seems to me), a message occurs stating that your preference had been recorded by the system, but actually nothing happens.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/746179/get-post-feedback-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voting is a privilege you have to earn. If you don't have at least [15 rep points](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), you cannot upvote; and if you don't have at least [125 rep points](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), you cannot downvote. This is done in part to make sure you understand how the community works before you start judging its content. The page [Privileges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) contains more information about other privileges you can get by contributing to this site.

If you don't comply with these restrictions, your vote will not be materialised. The vote is recorded internally, and it may be used by the developers as useful information. They track these kinds of actions, for statistical purposes. But, for all practical purposes, your vote will be useless. It will never be taken into account as far as what users can see.

You may find [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259583/346882) meta post useful if you want some more details.

Comment: The anonymous feedback is not entirely inaccessible, but I don't fully recall the channels for seeing those scores, or what (if any) rep requirements they have.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thanks for the info, I didn't know that.

Comment: Ah, yeah, it's recorded in the data explorer: http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/queries?q=Anonymous+feedback. A bit too clunky to be very useful but still worth dipping into now and again.

Comment: Woah, that's pretty crazy. I have some surprisingly extreme anonymous feedback on physics. And very little on SO. I'm perplexed.

Comment: @tpg2114 Yeah, in my experience, the anonymous feedback on SE is rarely actionable (and much more subject to unknowable parameters such as, say, how prominent the thread is on external search results). Which, really, is a good reason why it's off in some corner of the data explorer instead of prominently displayed.